# OpenLayers select.on event listener fires multiple times (renders multiple)

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers, rendering, react

I am using hook React. How to render event only once instead multiple times useless?

When I am selecting a feature, it renders multiple times

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
const translate = new ol.interaction.Translate({
   features: select.getFeatures(),
});

var layer_square = new ol.layer.Vector({
   source: source,
   style: [styles],
});

const layersCollections = [baseSource, layer_square];

const initMap = () => {
   map = new ol.Map({
      interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([select, translate]),
      renderer: 'webgl',
      target: 'map',
      layers: layersCollections,
      view: view,
   });
};

useEffect(() => {
      if (isMounted) {
         map.updateSize()
         select.on('select', (event: any) => {
            var selected = event.selected
            console.log(selected)
            if (selected.length) {
               selected.forEach((feature: ol.Feature) => {
            }
         })
      } else {
         setIsMounted(true);
         initMap()

      }
   },);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have solved that issue.
It was my mistake, I am changing all updates inside one `useEffect`, it should be done separately like that:

```
useEffect(() => {
      if (isMounted) {
         map.updateSize()
      } else {
         setIsMounted(true);
         initMap()
      }
   }); 

useEffect(() => {
            select.on('select', (event: any) => {
            var selected = event.selected
            console.log(isMounted)
            console.log(selected)
            if (selected.length) {
               selected.forEach((feature: ol.Feature) => {
            }
         })
      } 
  },[select]);
```